# Is there a need to catch exceptions that I've speciffied in throws clause?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throws

Is there a need to catch exceptions that I've specified in throws clause? And viceversa, is there a need to specify exceptions catched?

```
public method() throws IOException, SQLException {
     ...
     try {
          ....
     }catch(IOException | SQLException ex) {
          ex.getMessage();
     }
}
```

Comment: The above code makes no sense. the method will never actually throw those Exceptions, since you catch them, yet you will force the calling methods to either catch the exceptions (which will never be thrown) or declare them as 'could be thrown' through your entire flow. So: either catch them, or throw them. But, no, you shouldn't have a throws if you catch them.

Comment: No. You either throw exceptions in your method signature or catch them. You shouldn't do both. If you do, the `catch` will execute

Comment: This is basically that game you play with the dog - pretending you're throwing a ball but then holding on to it and seeing your dog run after absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit need to catch the exceptions that were specified in the signature.

Ideally the answer depends, If you want to propagate the exception to the caller then, don't catch the exception.  Let the caller know about the exceptoin and decide on what to do on next, like showing a message, recovery actions, cleanup etc. Its a good practise not to catch the exception

Comment: Ok, When I catch exception locally in the method that it throws (withouth specifying them), then when I call that method I don't have to catch them. Another question is why methods from API just specify the exception and don't catch them locally so that the users can call them withowt handling exceptions? Is this from performance reasons?

Comment: Not at all, performance does not into picture.  There is no harm in catching the exception in method, but as i said, it is always better to propagate the exception to the caller.  Caller should know, why it got failed. If you consume the exception, caller does not know what happened inside caller unless you write some hceck on the return vaule. It's not mandatory, but its good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could be in a situation where you need to catch any exceptions for logging purposes or for actual business logic: If *this* operation fails, then, use *this* operation as backup.

In your case, you are swallowing exceptions, since it would seem that nothing is being done with what `ex.getMessage()` is returning, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

- You can declare a method that `throws Exception` if you want the
  calling method to catch the exception.
- If you want that same method should handle exception, then you have to catch it.
- You should either catch exceptions of declare the method as `throws`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no". If you catch the exceptions in your code then you won't throw them (as previous comment noted), and thus there is no need to declare them in the throws clause. Conversely, if you're trying to throw them to your callers you shouldn't catch them. The only exception to that is that you might want to catch the exception and log it here for some reason, and then re-throw it for handling farther up the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Your method doesn't need to declare it throws those exceptions, because you catch them within the method.  `throws` should be used when an exception can be thrown out of a method and must be handled further up the call tree.

In this example, `MyCheckedException` is an exception that may be thrown out of your method and must be handled by the calling method, either by having that method catch the exception or also declare that it throws it.

```
public method() throws MyCheckedException {
    ...
    try {
        ....
    } catch(IOException | SQLException ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

If an exception is or extends RuntimeException, you don't need to declare that it's thrown (but there are deeper design issues here).

Answer (score 0):

The concept of catch exception is to indicate that some thing go wrong.To the user  and to the developer.
always is good to catch the exception and write to log  what is wrong. The more detailes is better, it's easier to fix code.
But if you specific exception like sqlException you can skip another kind of exceptions that can be thrown.

Answer (score -1):

There are two types of Exceptions:

Checked and Unchecked.

[This page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/) says:

> Checked: are the exceptions that are checked at compile time
>
> Unchecked are the exceptions that are not checked at compiled time
>
> ```
>             +-----------+
>           | Throwable |
>             +-----------+
>              /         \
>           /           \
>       +-------+          +-----------+
>       | Error |          | Exception |
>       +-------+          +-----------+
>     /  |  \            /     |    \
>       \______/            \______/     \
>                                    +------------------+
>     unchecked       checked        | RuntimeException |
>                                    +------------------+
>                                     /   |    |      \
>                                     \________________/
>
>                                         unchecked
> ```

so this a general rule if a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception

Also [on this site](http://www.javatpoint.com/throws-keyword-and-difference-between-throw-and-throws), it says:

> Exception Handling is mainly used to handle the checked exceptions. If
>   there occurs any unchecked exception such as NullPointerException, it
>   is programmers fault that he is not performing check up before the
>   code being used.

Comment: Please, always give credit to the source you quote from. [The source](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/)

Comment: @Sufian http://www.javatpoint.com/throws-keyword-and-difference-between-throw-and-throws

Comment: Add that to your question please.